# Not able to add custom domain in salesforce, CNAME validation failing

Tags: community, force.com, force.com-sites, custom-domain

I have setup a community in salesforce, and trying to add a domain for it.Every time, I try to add domain name as `subdomain.mydomain.com`, it gives me below error

Error: Salesforce.com can't validate the domain. The CNAME record may still be processing (which can take up to 24 hours), or the domain may not belong to you. Make sure the domain name `subdomain.mydomain.com` uses `subdomain.mydomain.com.<orgId>.live.siteforce.com` as its CNAME target and try again later.

I added a CNAME in DNS Management three days before and it has propagated successfully. Checked on 'www.whatsmydns.net' and it shows CNAME is correctly pointing to `subdomain.mydomain.com.****orgid****.live.siteforce.com`

It seems to be a bug to me as we followed the help & training tutorial for same and followed all steps. Please can anyone help me out in this.

Comment: Have you contacted support?

Comment: Not Yet, Actually I thought first I could check with the public forums, Actually that helps always.

Comment: I have had a similar problem where the CNAME record had a '.' appended to it in error because of the layout of the email requesting it from the supplier. By getting that removed it worked.

Comment: I checked the CNAME setting correctly, even I did that myself.